# Javascript and CSS: resource not found or not accessible

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I'm developing a couple of packages for plone 4.2. For some reason, when I install `mypackage.blah` through `mypackage.policy`, it loses access to its resourceDirectories, and its CSS and javascript are unavailable.

If I install `mypackage.blah` alone, it works fine. But I'm trying to install it using `mypackage.policy`, so I declared `mypackage.blah` as a dependency in `setup.py` and `metadata.xml`. When I install `mypackage.policy`, it install `mypackage.blah`, and its JS and CSS resources are registered, but portal_javascript they marked the files as "resource not found or innaccesible". It's as if it ignored the resourceDirectory directives.

**What could be happening for resourceDirectory to be ignored?**

Originally `mypackage.policy` used z3c.autoinclude, but I tried including `mypackage.blah` configuration directly in `mypakcage.policy` and even in `buildout.cfg`, and the problem persisted. There are no error traces in the log or console.

Any idea on how can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Did you upgrade collective.js.jqueryui? I did that and it REMOVED all other javascript!

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm using the latest plone 4.2 and collective.js.jqueryui = 1.8.13.1. I had an instance that was upgraded and it's working fine there, but when I create a new instance, I got that nasty behaviour. But could it that be the cause? By the symptoms it seems as if resourceDirectory has being ignored.

Comment: I don't know - it just happened to me on Friday, and I had meant to investigate the upgrade step to check that there wasn't a bug, but it certainly looked as if it replaced the entire javascript registry with just the values for _collective.js.jqueryui_ rather than appending/inserting them. Which would have the effect of ensuring there were no entries for your project... In my case, I restored the backup from an hour earlier, and then did a full upgrade to Plone 4.3 (successfully), but I still need to check that upgrade step.

Comment: If this is true, it's something you must report in the collective.js.jqueryui issue tracker at https://github.com/collective/collective.js.jqueryui/issues

Answer (score 1):

I went into the ZMI->portal_CSS-> bundles (tab) and changed from 'jQueryUI' to 'default' in the 3 boxes.  if it already is default, go to ZMI->portal_javacripts-> bundles (tab) and change 'jQueryUI' to 'default' in the 3 boxes.